# What is the difference between transferring and depositing

Tags: fraud

I'd like to know what the difference is between transferring Bitcoins and depositing them, more specifically to activate a wallet.

I've transfered  a huge amount of BTC into a trading platform. Now the platform requests that I deposit 0.002btc which will be added to my existing balance, before I can withdraw my BTC.

Is this normal?

Comment: In the realm of Bitcoin, transferring and depositing is the same. In your relationship with a trading third party, terminology is something you and your third party agree to. You might have accepted their terms of use. You need their customer support, not us.

Comment: This also sounds like a scam.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I needed to know